# VSCode Terminal Fish prompt not on the same line as the directory path

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VScode-Insiders and from time to time (depends on the update) my prompt (I use fish shell) ends up on two lines instead of the same line like it is supposed to be. Standard Vscode doesn't seem to have this issue...

Is it related to Insiders tinkering with settings and messing things up sometimes or is there a specific setting to prevent this behavior ?
[Here's an exemple of the weird prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkxE2.png)

As you can see, the prompt Decoration is always a line after the actual prompt line.. I tried disabling it but it changes nothing.

I tried copy pasting terminal settings from VScode over to VScode-Insiders but it didn't change anything and I can't seem to find any related settings in the terminal settings of the IDE...

Comment: what happens if you disable shell integration in your settings? possibly related change: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139400

Comment: I encourage you to raise an issue ticket using the `Help: Report Issue...` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). Once you do, please [edit] your question post to add a link to it so I can follow along with it as well.

Comment: related on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/14woy2z/is_there_anyone_who_knows_about_the_issue_of/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3, https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/14sjjx8/weird_fish_shell_prompt_in_vscodeinsiders/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3